# Is it safe to use reference to the Application where Context is required?

Tags: android

As it stands we need to pass a `Context` in many places within Android application. I'm wondering how safe it is to use a `static` variable which refers to the `Application` class instance in such places? For example, I have a `static` method in one of my `Activities` and I can't use `this` (as `Activity`) or something because the method is `static`, so I'm guessing to use the `Application.instance` reference which is initialized on each application start. Is it ok you think? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context. also check this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your method and what you are trying to do with the Context. If you want to get resources like a String or Drawable from your app, then it is save to use the Application Context. But if you want to display a Dialog, then you definitely should use the Activity Context.

As far as I know, for a Toast you can use the Application Context as well.

Comment: Yeah, what I really do there is showing a Toast and retrieving a resource from there also.

Comment: Then it should be fine using the Application Context.